# Docker flask - jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: index.html

Tags: python, docker, flask, docker-compose

New to docker and trying to run a flask mysql app but getting a  jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: index.html . No errors if I run `python app.py` outside of docker

Directory structure

```
  -docker-compose.yml
  -app
    -templates
          -index.html
    -app.py
    -Dockerfile
    -requirements.txt
  -db
    -init.sql
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "2"
services:
  app:
    build: ./app
    links:
      - db
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
      - "32000:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    volumes:
      - ./db:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/:ro
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.6

EXPOSE 5000

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

ENV IN_DOCKER_CONTAINER Yes

COPY app.py /app
CMD python app.py
```

requirements.txt:

```
Flask==1.0.2
Jinja2==2.10
gunicorn==19.6.0
flask-mysql
```

part of my app.py:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    conn = mysql.connect()
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    try:
        query = '''SELECT * from favorite_colors'''
        cursor.execute(query)
        data = cursor.fetchall()
    except Exception as e:
        return str(e)
    finally:
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()
    return render_template('index.html', MyExampleVar=str(data))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Dockerfile` only copies `requirements.txt` and `app.py` into the image.  In order for the dockerized `app.py` to have access to `templates` and its contents, you need to copy `templates` as well by adding the line:

```
COPY templates /app/
```